# How to include hdf5 header files in a C program on Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, compilation, hdf5

I am trying to learn how to program in C, and I want to be able to import data into my C program from a .hdf file.

I am using a mid 2009 MacBook Pro with Mac OS X lion.

I think I am having problems, because I didn't know where on my system to put all the header files associated with hdd (remember, I'm a bit of a noob). So I just downloaded the hdf5-1.8.9-freebsd-shared folder from the hdd website, and manually dragged all the .h files from the `/include` subdirectory into the `/usr/include` directory onto my computer.

When I try to compile my .c program using the normal gcc terminal command, I get an error which is along the lines of (sorry about the formatting but I think the exact error doesn't matter too much anyway):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_H5check_version", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Fcreate", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Screate_simple", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5open", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5T_STD_I32LE_g", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Dcreate2", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5T_NATIVE_INT_g", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Dwrite", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Dclose", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Sclose", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Fclose", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Fopen", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Dopen2", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
  "_H5Dread", referenced from:
      _main in cc9FVO6S.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Though the exact error varies depending on exactly what code I am trying to compile. This was generated when I tried to compile a [sample program](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/examples/examples-by-api/hdf5-examples/1_8/C/H5D/h5ex_d_rdwr.c).

Does anybody have any experience with getting hdf5 to work in C in Mac OS X? I have found it all very confusing.

By the way, I normally use python, and frequently use h5py without trouble.

Comment: It seems like a rather random guess that the freebsd version of the library works on OSX. Find an OSX version, or compile one yourself. In addition to including the header files you also need to link to the hdf5 library,  the error messages here says you havn't

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your linker when you are using a library using `-l<library-name>` and `-L<library-dir>` for non-standard locations.

If you installed hdf5 in `/usr/local/hdf5`, you need something like:

```
gcc -o h5ex_d_rdwr h5ex_d_rdwr.c -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -L/usr/local/hdf5/lib -lhdf5
```

If you are using the High-Level API, also add `-lhdf5_hl`.

---

If you have `pkg-config` installed and it is aware of your hdf5 installation, you can let it do it for you:

```
gcc -o h5ex_d_rdwr h5ex_d_rdwr.c `pkg-config hdf5 --cflags --libs`
```